# Realtime database console shows empty database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

Realtime database console shows empty database and unable to load rules error message under the rules tab. I connected it to an android app. The database is populated before but i can't seem to find any data in it now. what must have gone wrong

Answer (score 1):

this happens when you create new project from android studio assisstant try to create new project manully and add the web api key and etc manully .

Answer (score 1):

First be sure that your database rules look like that

"rules": {
".read": true,
".write": true
}
}

Second add link to your database in java code like that

```
 FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://link to your database/");
```

Comment: Or as a last resort, try re-adding the json file.